# Unable to start kubectl and helm from pycharm terminal/run

Tags: python, bash, kubernetes, pycharm, kubernetes-helm

I have a script which try to start subprocess with kubectl command like this:

```
params = [
            "kubectl",
            "get",
            "svc",
            "-o=jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.ports[*].port}'"
          ]
sp = subprocess.run(params, capture_output=True)
```

But I always get this error:

```
    >               raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
E               FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'kubectl': 'kubectl'

/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py:1522: FileNotFoundError
```

From pycharm terminal I can’t start kubectl too, but in my Linux terminal this work flawlessly without root user. User id for pycharm terminal and bash are same. 
How I can fix this problem?

I tried to move kubectl and helm into project and use "./kubectl" instead, this somewhat works, but I guess kubectl didn't manage to use its configs, because I get a connection error:

```
    >           raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
E           requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='host', port=8090): Max retries exceeded with url: /xss/1027019261true.1.php?test=%3Cscript%3Ealert(0);%3C/script%3E (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f1daaf4b090>: Failed to establish a
```

new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

(host edited by me in question)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the full path to kubectl binary.

I would use Kubernetes python client for any interactions with Kubernetes.